# Solution in shift/reduce conflict at bison grammar

Tags: bison, parser-generator, lr-grammar

I'm trying to write a parser for tiny Visual Basic language.
And I can't resolve next shift/reduce conflict. I have these rules:

```
simple_type_name:
    qualified_type_name
    | primitive_type_name;

qualified_type_name:
    ID
    | qualified_type_name PERIOD ID;

primitive_type_name: BOOLEAN|CHAR|STRING|BYTE|SBYTE|USHORT|SHORT|UINTEGER|INTEGER|ULONG|LONG|SINGLE|DOUBLE;
```

Bison says me:

```
simple_type_name  ->  qualified_type_name .   (rule 20)
qualified_type_name  ->  qualified_type_name . PERIOD ID   (rule 23)

PERIOD  shift, and go to state 41

PERIOD  [reduce using rule 20 (simple_type_name)]
$default reduce using rule 20 (simple_type_name)
```

So, what is the right solution in this conflict?

Comment: Do you reference qualified_type_name anywhere else in your grammar?

Comment: No.It is only location of this rule.

Comment: You need to show where `simple_type_name` is referenced in the grammar as that's the source of the problematic reduction that causes the conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have some other rule in the grammar where `simple_type_name` is followed by a `PERIOD`.  Something like:

```
expression: simple_type_name PERIOD expression
```

perhaps?

The problem is that it needs more lookahead to determine if what comes after the `PERIOD` is a simple `ID` that makes this a qualified type name or something else that would make it a simple type name.

One possible solution (impossible to tell, as you don't show enough of your grammar) is to unfactor `simple_type_name` where it is followed by a period -- duplicate the rule, replacing `simple_type_name` with both `qualified_type_name` and `primitive_type_name`.  With the above `expression` example, that would be:

```
expression: qualified_type_name PERIOD expression
          | primitive_type_name PERIOD expression
```

Depending on the rest of your grammar it might be necessary or desirable to completely unfactor `simple_type_name`, replacing all mentions of it with duplicated rules and deleting the `simple_type_name` rule itself

**edit**

Ok, you've linked more of your grammar, so we can see that the problematic use of `simple_type_name` is in a trailing context (at the end of the rhs of a rule), so simple unfactoring is not enough.  You may be able to fix it by repeated unfactoring (unfactor `simple_type_name` as described above, then unfactor `simple_expression` and/or `type_name` as well).  The goal is to push the unfactoring to a rule that has

```
    ... some-nonterminal PERIOD ...
```

on the right side, and replace that with rules

```
    ... other-nonterminal PERIOD ... | ... qualified_type_name PERIOD ...
```

where `other-nonterminal` is a duplicate of `some-nonterminal` with the rules that lead to a single `qualified_type_name` removed.

Unfortunately this can easily lead to an exponential blowup in the size of the grammar, so may be impractical.  In that case the only option may be to use a more powerful parsing method, such as bison's `%glr-parser` option or backtracking with [btyacc](https://github.com/ChrisDodd/btyacc).